# c# Почему не требуется реализовать интрефейс?

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Почему мне не требуется реализовать метод CompareTo?

```
class A<D> where D : IComparable
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот  метод должен быть не у класса `A`, а у типа `D`. Вы же на `D` накладываете ограничение.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы наложили ограничение на шаблон (обобщение) типа `D`, то есть класс `A` будет использовать тип `D`, который в свою очередь должен реализовывать интерфейс `IComparable`.
Данная конструкция позволяет использовать метод `CompareTo` в классе `A` от экземпляра типа `D` без приведения типа:

```
class A<D> where D : IComparable
{
    public D variable { get; set; }

    private int Compare(IComparable source)
    {
        return variable.CompareTo(source);
    }
}
```